# Why does crossfilter not sort or filter my data correctly?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter

I'm learning crossfilter and want to filter some data.
So I have this big [json file](https://www.file-upload.net/download-13625051/data2.json.html) (It's actually csv) with almost 4 million lines of data.

The file looks like this:
`timestamp,speed,power,distance,temperature,heart_rate,cadence,altitude,lat,long
1514806362,6569,172,6.63,14,90,87,2548,500870453,33664825`

And all I'm trying to do is filter the distance.

```
d3.csv('data2.json').then(function(data) {
  data.forEach(function(d, i) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.timestamp);
  });

  // Create instance of crossfilter with dataset
  var cf = crossfilter(data);

  // Ask crossfilter how many rows it has / Size of data
  dataSize = cf.size();
  console.log("Data size: " + dataSize);

  function parseDate(d) {
    return new Date(d*1000);
  }

  var distanceDimension = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.distance; });
  console.log("Creating delay dimension");

  // List top 3 distance
  distanceDimensionTop3 = distanceDimension.top(3);
  console.log("Top 3 distance");
  console.table(distanceDimensionTop3);


  // List bottom 3 distance
  distanceDimensionBottom3 = distanceDimension.bottom(3);
  console.log("Bottom 3 distance");
  console.table(distanceDimensionBottom3);


  // Apply filter to get only distance above 5000 meters
  distanceDimension.filterFunction(function(d) {return d > 5000;}); 
  console.log("Appliyng distance filter for only distance above 5000 meters");


  // List bottom 3 distance
  console.log("Bottom 3 distance with filter applied");
  console.table(distanceDimension.bottom(3));
});
```

But somehow my code fails right at the beginning listing the top 3 distance.
I get a value of `99999.88` but in my data file, I have bigger values.

Also when I apply the filter to my dimension it doesn't filter right.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for asking on SO - this is the best place for support questions. I saw the [question on GitHub](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/issues/137) first, so I answered it there. There's no need to cross-post crossfilter or dc.js questions as the same people follow both forums.